# Proton's half life (Energy-dependent)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, grand-unification, proton-decay

Proton's half life has a lower estimated bound in 10^33 years aprox. This is due to the enormous mass of the X boson, predicted by some GUTs. So my question is: if the free proton is in a high energy state, it has more energy (ready to be "used") and thus it would be easier to create the X boson needed. Is this implying a energy-dependent half life? If so, has this dependence been  calculated somewhere? I'd love to have some references if possible. Sorry for my english and thanks.

Comment: There's a misconception here: it is the mass (a Lorentz-invariant quantity) which can be "used" to create particles in a decay. Alternatively you may think of it as the energy in the centre-of-momentum frame. The relation $E=mc^2$ only works at rest. More generally it is $E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4$.

Answer (score 1):

All decays behave the same way, the mass of the mediating particle affects the lifetime when measured at the rest frame.

The lifetime of [the muon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon) for example is given as ~2.2μsec, this number is for a muon at rest. Energetic muons are relativistic, and so time dilation
of   [a high energy muon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation_of_moving_particles) will give a longer lifetime according to the relativistic effects.

The same would be true for the possible proton decay, except that [the mass of the X, ~10^15 GeV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_and_Y_bosons) is so huge  and the lifetime this implies (~10^33 seconds) so large  the probability of decay could not be enhanced in the existing accelerators.